# How can I print the value of variable used in meta_query in a Wp_query?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

```
$today = date('Ymd');

      $homepageEvents = new WP_Query(array(
          'posts_per_page' => 2,
          'post_type' => 'event',
          'meta_key' => 'event_date',
          'order_by' => 'meta_value_num',
          'order' =>'ASC',
          'meta_query' => array(
            array(
              'key' => 'event_date',
              'compare' => '>=',
              'value' => $today
            ))
```

I followed a tutorial and ran across the code, but when I try to see the result on my page it shows nothing. Right now, I'm trying to display the event_date value so I can edit it if possible, what am I supposed to do? (using wordpress, acf plugin -> event_date is the custom field name generated by acf)

Comment: Inside of the post loop, you can do  `echo get_post_meta($post_id, $key="event_date", true);` Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

If the custom field 'event_date' uses the same date formatting as your $today variable, you can do this:

```
<?php
$today = date('Ymd');
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'meta_key' => 'event_date',
    'meta_value' => $today,
    'meta_compare' => '>=',
    'order' =>'ASC',
    'order_by' => 'meta_value_num',
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <div><?php the_title(); ?></div>
        <div><?php echo get_post_meta($post_id, 'event_date', true); ?></div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```